# Finding closest number from two arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

Recently one of my data servers went down and a large number of video files are damaged (over 15,000 files, or more than 60TB). I wrote a script to check all files and put results in a very big log.txt file (almost 8GB).

I wrote code to find all lines starting with `"Input #0"` and lines which contain `"damaged"`, then added their line numbers to `ArrayList`'s. Next, I need to compare those two ArrayLists and find the closest line number in `list2` to the number in `list1` so I can get back file names from the log file.

For example:
if `list1` contains numbers {1, 5, 45, 55, 100, 2000... etc}
and `list2` contains numbers {50, 51, 53, 2010... etc} the result should be {45, 2000... etc}

This is my current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Log {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        File file = new File("C:\\log.txt");

        try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file);

         int lineNum = 0;
         int lineNum2 = 0;


         while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scanner.nextLine();
             String line2 = scanner.nextLine();

             lineNum++;
             lineNum2++;

         if((line.startsWith("Input #0"))) { 

             list1.add(lineNum);
           } 

         if((line2.contains("damaged"))) { 

             list2.add(lineNum2);
           }

         }
```

This is what I'm getting from the code above:

```
list1 [5, 262, 304, 488, 523, 1189, 1796, 2503, 2722, 4052, 4201, 4230, 4298, 4312, 4559, 4887, 4903, 5067....]
list2 [1838, 1841, 1842, 1844, 1851, 1861, 1865, 1866, 1868, 1875, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1886, 1887, 1891....]
```

Some log data:

```
Input #0, mpegvideo, from '/cinegy/cinegy/VIDEO/BSF/BLOK 3 - 14. NOVHighb668ca7d201411141051110636.m2v':
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Data with damage:

```
Input #0, mpegvideo, from '/cinegy/cinegy/VIDEO/BSF/BLOK 3 - 14. NOVHighb668ca7d201411141051110636.m2v':
.
.
.
.
.
[error 0x090010] file damaged at 16 09
[error 0x090010] file damaged at 19 15
```

The log for each individual file does not contain any pattern except for the first 5-6 lines or so. Both damaged and non-damaged files contain info written in 20 to 100+ lines.

So, from these numbers the first result should be number 1796.

I'm pretty much a novice in Java and I need help.

Comment: The example you provide is not what you describe:'if list1 contains numbers {1, 5, 45, 55, 100, 2000... etc} and list2 contains numbers {50, 51, 53, 2010... etc} result should be {45, 2000... etc}' Why? Please explain how these lists have this result.

Comment: Do you have a specific range in mind? Like if the numbers have a difference of less than 50 it should output?

Comment: What's the next number after 1796 ?

Comment: Well, to the number 45 from list1 the closest number from list2 is 50. But it needs to escape numbers 1 and 5 because the closest number to the number 50 is 45 etc.

Comment: In my log file there is several million lines with unique number. Some of those lines are starting with 'Index #0', the rest of line is the name of the data that is checked. After each 'Index #0' line are lines with various contents, but each 'Index #0' line doesn't contain line or lines that contain 'damaged'. So, that means that those files are O.K. I need line numbers from log file of damaged files so I can get their names and replace them with new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined two scanners (seems unnecessary) but you are only using one of them and calling nextline() twice on it. It looks like that is not intended and as a consequence the results you are getting are erroneous. It would be very helpful if you could post a sample excerpt from your logfile (you can filter the sensitive data) so that we can determine what the best approach is for this.

I think you should scrap your current approach because it does not seem like an efficient way to solve your problem of needing to find filenames of damaged files.

Depending on how your data looks, you can use regular expressions and possibly even extract the filenames directly into a Set.

**Edit:** Added some rough code that should do the job for you if you are indeed correct that each file starts with "Input #0". As long as there is a pattern in the log data for each file, then you should always be able to extract the data you need directly instead of going through the mess of matching entries from two separate arraylists.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Set<String> damagedFiles = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    File file = new File("C:\\log.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String filename = null;


    try {
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(line.startsWith("Input #0")){
                /*if desired, can use a regex lookahead to get only the path and filename
                    instead of the entire Input #0 line */
                filename = line;
            }
            if(line.contains("damaged")){
                if (filename != null){
                    damagedFiles.add(filename);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        for (String s : damagedFiles){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result I got when running this code on a sample log file where I named the damaged files dmg#.m2v

```
Input #0, mpegvideo, from '/cinegy/cinegy/VIDEO/BSF/BLOK 3 - 14. dmg1.m2v':
Input #0, mpegvideo, from '/cinegy/cinegy/VIDEO/BSF/BLOK 3 - 14. dmg2.m2v':
Input #0, mpegvideo, from '/cinegy/cinegy/VIDEO/BSF/BLOK 3 - 14. dmg3.m2v':
Input #0, mpegvideo, from '/cinegy/cinegy/VIDEO/BSF/BLOK 3 - 14. dmg4.m2v':
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Works like a charm and it is incredibly fast. One of my colleagues tried something similar in C#, and it took almost 2 hours to get result from 200Mb log sample, this code finished in 8 sec. Thank you my friend for your great help.

Comment: Glad to be of help. One more thing..You can consider using a HashSet instead of LinkedHashSet if you are not concerned with the ordering of the file names that you retrieve. HashSet is a little bit more efficient and I take it that with an 8gb log file you need all the performance you can get.

Comment: My friend, believe me, it is fast enough. From another 2.5GB log file I got result back in less than 70 seconds. I have to mention that I am running this code on my two years old laptop, so yes, this code is just PERFECT. P.S. +3 seconds on writing result (around 3k lines) to output text file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small code that will do the work, but I don't know if you want redundant values in the result, so I saved them in a list and in a set, choose the one you prefer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list1 = {5, 262, 304, 488, 523, 1189, 1796, 2503, 2722, 4052, 4201, 4230, 4298, 4312, 4559};
        int[] list2 = {1838, 1841, 1842, 1844, 1851, 1861, 1865, 1866, 1868, 1875, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881};

        ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> resultSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){

            for(; j < list1.length; j++){
                if(list1[j] > list2[i])
                    break;
            }
            resultList.add(list1[j-1]);
            resultSet.add(list1[j-1]);

        }

        System.out.println(resultList);
        System.out.println(resultSet);
    }
```

Output:

```
[1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796, 1796]
[1796]
```

Comment: I'll try to implement your code and wait for the result.

Comment: Code works good for first 2.800.000 lines, but then stops and won't continue. Braheem solved with another approach. Thank you for your help, it was very helpful.